# Python - Email send -- pass variable into HTML Encoder

Tags: python, html, html-email, encode, send

The original coding works if I use the example code and use the the proper credentials. (If you are trying to experiment with this, the "password" is generated in/through the Gmail Account. )

The (old) code sends a static message. I want to send a dynamic message.

I'm trying to pass a varaible into the HTML Body...

**html_txt = missing_compare_df['name'].to_list()**

```
if missing_count==0:
    msg = "0 Missing Websites"
    
else:
    'Website Count Error!'


today = date.today()
today = today.strftime('%m-%d-%y')

from_address = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
to_address = "xxxxx@gmail.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = msg
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address
```

- ##### (old) Code From Example   <- This works!

```
# Create the message (HTML).
# html = """\
# Scraping & Import Complete - Initiating ML.
# """*
```

##### /(old) Code From Example

#### / This does not work (I'm trying to pass a variable)

```
**html = html_txt
```

#### /\ THIS DOES NOT WORK /###

```
# Record the MIME type - text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container
msg.attach(part1)

# Credentials
username = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'  
password = 'xxxxxxxx'

# Sending the email
## note - this smtp config worked for me, I found it googling around, you may have to tweak the # (587) to get yours to work
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)  
server.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())  
server.quit()
print('email sent')
```

The error message says:
Cell In[43], line 44, in send_email()
41 html = html_txt
43 # Record the MIME type - text/html.
---> 44 part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
46 # Attach parts into message container
47 msg.attach(part1)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\email\mime\text.py:34, in MIMEText.**init**(self, _text, _subtype, _charset, policy)
32 if _charset is None:
33     try:
---> 34         _text.encode('us-ascii')
35         _charset = 'us-ascii'
36     except UnicodeEncodeError:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: `html_txt = missing_compare_df['name'].to_list()` html_text is a list.  You can't pass a list to `MIMEText()`.